# MOSS 2007 scopes in a custom-built advanced search page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm attempting (futilely) to create a custom advanced search page for my department's SharePoint site. I've been using this article as a guide,

http://tqclarkson.com/2007/10/26/creating-a-custom-advanced-search-box-in-moss-2007/

I've had some success copying the code of the advanced search web part and modifying it to my needs. However, I'm having some struggles with scopes.

Some background...

- We are currently running MOSS 2007
- Our company houses all its intranet sites under one GIGANTIC site collection
- I am a site owner, but not the site collection administrator (that is controlled by IT corporate). Therefore I don't have access to central administration which houses most of the search settings.
- IT has not set up any custom scopes (and just trust me when I say asking them to do so would be completely impractical).

I need to scope the advanced search web part's queries to just our site or its libraries. In a perfect world, I would just create custom scopes for this purpose, but as I mentioned that's not an option here.

I've tried using the URL property to restrict the results. Problem is the search has to be executed on EVERY RECORD in the database (which I'm sure is unfathomably huge). I did a test query which took over 5 minutes to result! Definitely not a practical solution.

So that's where I'm stuck. I need to scope the queries but can't figure out how else to do it. Any advice is welcome. Thanks as always!

Comment: This question is better suited for [Sharepoint community](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that even existed. I'll post there.